# Alternative to eval() for templating Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-docs

**Background:**
We use Google Docs to create documents.  We have created template documents, that require two types of changes before they are finalized for use:

1. a simple text replace; and
2. a conditional text replace;

These are indicated in the document using ***tags***.  Using Google Apps Script, we then replace the tags as needed in the template to create a final document.  The tags will contain variables.

1. The simple text replace tag is represented as follows: ***${$SomeVar}***, and the variable would be ***$SomeVar***.

*Example:*
`Dear ${$Client}.`

The remainder of this post will not deal with the simple text replace.

2. The conditional text replace tag is represented as either: ***${if CONDITION} XXXXX ${end}*** or as  ***${if CONDITION} XXXXX ${else} YYYYY ${end}***, depending on whether we need an alternate (i.e. else) or not.

*Example:*
Omitting an example without the 'else', the conditional text replace could be used in a contract or final reporting letter:
`You ${if ($Paid==true)}have already paid us in full${else}still have a balance outstanding${end}.` (note the 'You ' before the if tag and the '.' after the end tag)
Depending on the value of the variable `$Paid`, this would yield either
`You have already paid us in full.` or
`You still have a balance outstanding.`

*N.B.:* The condition can be anything that evaluates to a boolean.  It could be `someBool==true` or `someNum>2` or `someString.trim().len>4` or similar.  We would like to not limit the possible content of the condition.

**Current Implementation:**
We have the above working correctly by searching for an opening if tag, an else-tag (if it exists) and the end tag.  It then keeps the required text and deletes the tags (as per the example above).

Unfortunately, we are using the dreaded javascript eval() as follows (using the example above):
`eval($Paid==true)`.

Here is the exact code that verifies the conditional:

```
var condString = ifString.replace(/^\$\{\s*if\s*/,"").replace(/\s*\}$/,"").replace(/\$(\w+)/g, "tags[\"$1\"]");
return eval(condString);
```

Here is a dumb-down and highly simplified version of the code, omitting the parsing for the `${else}` and `${end}` tags, as well as any real functionality:

```
function ParseConditionalTags() {

    /* parameters passed in to function, here hardcoded strictly for demonstration purposes
    **
    **
    */
    var orig = DriveApp.getFileById("SomeTemplateGoogleDocId");
    var doc = DocumentApp.openById(orig.makeCopy(orig.getName() + "_1", orig.getParents().next()).getId());
    /* doc: the newly created Google Doc, in a/the same folder as the original template */

    var variables = {};
    variables["BooleanVar"] = false;
    variables["num"] = 11;
    /* variables: the variables passed in to the function, which will then be replaced as required in the opening if-tag */

    /*
    **
    **
    ** end hardcoded parameters for demonstration purposes */


    /* helper variables
    **
    **
    */

    /* get the body as it is frequently used */
    var body = doc.getBody();

    /* this is the regular expression (strings) for the opening if-tag */
    var ifRegExpString = "\\$\\{if\\s+[^\\}\\s]+\\}";

    /* get the body as it is frequently used */
    var body = doc.getBody();

    /*
    **
    **
    ** end helper variables */



    /* search the body for an opening if-tag */
    var startRE = body.findText(ifRegExpString);

    var ifString;
    var condEval;

    while (startRE != null) {
        /* get the "${if /something/}" string */
        ifString = startRE.getElement().asText().getText().slice(startRE.getStartOffset(),startRE.getEndOffsetInclusive()+1);

        /* assume that variables must be only letters, numbers and underscores, which is incorrect as far as the JavaScript reference goes:
               https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_variables.asp
        */
        condEval = eval(ifString.replace(/^\$\{\s*if\s*/,"").replace(/\s*\}$/,"").replace(/\$(\w+)/g, "variables[\"$1\"]"));

        if (condEval) {
            /* the condition evaluates to true, so keep the text between the tags but delete the actual tags */
            /* this block is ommitted as it does not assist in demonstrating the question/issue */
        }
        else {
            /* the condition evaluates to false, so remove the tags and all text between them */
            /* this block is ommitted as it does not assist in demonstrating the question/issue */ 
        }
    }


    /* get the next opening if-tag */
    startRE = body.findText(ifRegExpString, startRE);
}
```

**Problem:**
We would like all of our users to be able to create template documents and to automate the finalized document (as above), but this is a huge security risk as anyone could insert some code in the template document, which would then be `eval()ed`:
`${ DoSomethingTerribleLikeDeleteAllFiles() }`

**What we've tried:**
We've tried using [Ultradox](https://www.ultradox.com/) but unfortunately it is lacking other needed behaviour.  Also, we would prefer not using other software, where we can't see the code (hence our wanting to build something ourselves).

**Questions:**
Short of building a complex parser for the conditional, can someone assist us in achieving our intended goal of building template documents with conditionals?
Alternately, does anyone know of any open source projects, which could assist?

**Edits:**

- Added the exact code used for the conditional eval statement.
- Re-added javascript tag (removed by someone else) as the question is about a javascript alternative to `eval()` (albeit applied to Google Apps Script).
- Added much simplified code demonstrating the use-case.
- Re-added, again, javascript tag, which was removed by Sourabh Choraria.  As this clearly pertains to javascript, why has this tag been removed twice?
- Clarified that the conditional does not need to be `==` or a lone variable.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205008/discussion-on-question-by-sjl-alternative-to-eval-for-templating-google-apps-s).

Comment: I assume your Google Doc has rich text formatting? If not, could you use https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/templates? Get the whole document body as a string and pass it to `HtmlService.createTemplate(...)`?

Comment: @IMTheNachoMan: Yes, the Google Doc has rich text formatting, as well as other non-HTML compatible features.  The final document is then a PDF.

Comment: Thinking about it more, it won't work because there is still the same risk where the editor could run any code. I think to achieve your goal, and to keep it secure, you're gonna need to end up building a complex parser to extract/exclude/prevent dangerous code.